# Skip first element in "for each" loop?

Tags: arrays, actionscript

I have an array of sprites called `segments` and I would like to skip the first element of `segments` in my for each loop. I'm doing this at the moment:

```
var first = true;
for each (var segment in this.segments)
{
    if(!first)
    {
        // do stuff
    }

    first == false;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Does ActionScript "fix" using `for..in` over Arrays? In JavaScript `for(i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) { doStuff(arr[i]) }` is the *correct way* to iterate over an Array and should be used instead... in which case skipping the first element is trivial (start at `i = 1`).

Comment: If you don't want to process each array entry, don't use `for each`. `For each` specifically means "for each", just like it says. Read the words literally, and if you don't want to process every item, use a standard `for` loop instead of `for each`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if its an array why not just:

```
for(var i:int = 1; i < this.segments.length; i++)
{

}
```

Comment: Well I don't know what the ultimate goal of this was. I figured if you want to pull out items from an array in order you would use for loop anyways

Comment: **Swift 5** raises error: "`C-style for statement has been removed in Swift 3`"

Answer (score 7):

This can also be done via "slice".
For example

```
for (var segment in this.segments.slice(1))
{
    
}
```

[`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) will copy the array without the first element.